# Typescript interface member with two types

Tags: typescript

I don't know if I have remembered correctly but can Typescript `interface` members be defined with multiple types?

*psuedo* typescript...:

```
interface IModel {
   field : string | Array;
}
```

Where `IModel.field` can be either a `string` or an `Array`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
interface IModel {
   field : string | Array<any>;
}

class MyClass1 implements IModel {
    field : string;
}

class MyClass2 implements IModel {
    field : Array<any>;
}
```

#### Update 1

Indecisive implementation ([Typescript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground));

```
class MyClass3 implements IModel {
    field : string | Array<any>;
}
```

Comment: so are you saying that the implementation can't also be indecisive?